# How can I schedule a release deployment with the VisualStudioServices client?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I am trying to use the VisualStudioServices client, mainly the ReleaseHttpClient, to schedule a deployment. Specifically, I am using UpdateReleaseEnvironmentAsync. However, whenever I attempt to schedule a deployment instead of deploying right away, I get an error.

I have tried using different statuses and gates but those did not work.

> Update to the scheduled time is not allowed in this state. Make sure
>   the environment is in progress and you have pending Pre Approvals.

I am hoping to actual schedule a deployment instead of attempting to deploy right away.

Update: I was finally able to get this to work by adding in approval steps before the deployment and then scheduling it.

Comment: According to your description, looks like you are using an approval in your release. Have you tried to update ApprovalStatus with pending https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1?

Comment: We are using automatic approvals. They worked automatically when I did not schedule the deployment. Is there a way I can create an approval and approve it? Or is it something along the lines of listing the approvals, finding the one, and approving it in the code?

Comment: Hi  Alexander Carpenter, Yes you are able to update an approval using Rest API. When you create release there are some options called during create release such as `ReleaseApproval`, you could find details here. Better to share your code here, we could try to follow your code to reproduce. I was using Rest API to create the schedule release.